# drop - down menu using JS onclick - what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

Just learing JS. I have created 3 dropdown menu with different choices and added JS function. HTML and CSS seems to be right. I am concerned about my JS, because it just does not work. Is the even right for that purpose? I am not sure if I use ".this" in the right place.

I would really appreciate any hints!

my JAVASCRIPT:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");

var arrow= document.querySelectorAll(".list_arrow");
var panel= document.querySelectorAll(".list_panel");



for (var i= 0; i < arrow.length; i++) {
  arrow[i].addEventListener('click', function showDiv(event) {

    if (panel.this.style.display == 'none') {  //panel(this.style.display=='none')?
        panel.this.style.display = 'block';
    }

    else {
        panel.this.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}

  });

HERE IS MY CSS
```

```css
.form {
  margin-top:50px;
}
.drop_down_list {
  border:1px solid #8de0d2;
  width: 280px;
  height:38px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top:22px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: relative;
}

.list_label {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #e2e2e2;
  font-family: 'ralewaylight', Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.list_arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid #24baa0;
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 14px;
  top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;

}


.list_panel {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 288px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 54px;
  display:none;
}

.list_panel li {
  margin-top:10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #585858;
}
```

```html
                <div class="form">


                  <div class="drop_down_list">
                      <span class="list_label">Choose a chair</span>
                      <span class="list_arrow"></span>
                      <ul class="list_panel">
                          <li>Clair</li>
                          <li>Margarita</li>
                          <li>Selena</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="drop_down_list">
                      <span class="list_label">Choose color</span>
                      <span class="list_arrow"></span>
                      <ul class="list_panel">
                          <li>red</li>
                          <li>black</li>
                          <li>orange</li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="drop_down_list">
                      <span class="list_label">Choose material</span>
                      <span class="list_arrow"></span>
                      <ul class="list_panel">
                          <li>a</li>
                          <li>b</li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `this` keyword refers to the current [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). It is of no use in the state you are using it. What I suggest is to locate the `list_panel` that is associated with the clicked arrow. There are numerous ways to do that, but you can use the following:

Note that I also added default `display-none` classes so that they get shown on the first click (this wasn't the case).

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");

var arrow= document.querySelectorAll(".list_arrow");

for (var i= 0; i < arrow.length; i++) {
  arrow[i].addEventListener('click', function showDiv(event) {
    
    // Find the panel associated with the clicked arrow.
   var parent = event.target.parentNode,
       currentPanel = parent.children[2];

    if (currentPanel.style.display == 'none') {  
        currentPanel.style.display = 'block';
    }

    else {
        currentPanel.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}

  });</script>
```

```css
.form {
  margin-top:50px;
}
.drop_down_list {
  border:1px solid #8de0d2;
  width: 280px;
  height:38px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top:22px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: relative;
}

.list_label {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #e2e2e2;
  font-family: 'ralewaylight', Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.list_arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid #24baa0;
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 14px;
  top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;

}


.list_panel {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 288px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 54px;
  display:none;
}

.list_panel li {
  margin-top:10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #585858;
}
```

```html
                <div class="form">


                  <div class="drop_down_list">
                      <span class="list_label">Choose a chair</span>
                      <span class="list_arrow"></span>
                      <ul class="list_panel" style='display: none'>
                          <li>Clair</li>
                          <li>Margarita</li>
                          <li>Selena</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="drop_down_list">
                      <span class="list_label">Choose color</span>
                      <span class="list_arrow"></span>
                      <ul class="list_panel" style='display: none'>
                          <li>red</li>
                          <li>black</li>
                          <li>orange</li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="drop_down_list">
                      <span class="list_label">Choose material</span>
                      <span class="list_arrow"></span>
                      <ul class="list_panel" style='display: none'>
                          <li>a</li>
                          <li>b</li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using jQuery to help you with `show()` and `hide()` functions, though it is said that [you might not need it](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com) :P

I don't understand the declaration of `panel`.. Thus I cannot go along `panel.this`.  My solution is attached here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akXqwA

The main problem is that, during the for-loop, the `i` will end at the value `3`.  When the event is triggered, `i` will always be `3`, and I cannot access the `panel` with `panel[i]`.

So I made a "hack" around it, by getting its nextElementSibling and changing its `style.display`.  Also, I have initialised the value with the HTML (`style="display: none;"`).  If you removed that part, the first click on the arrow will not show the items as the `style.display` value is not "none".  There is a way to avoid changing that in HTML: try playing with the line ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");

      var arrow = document.querySelectorAll(".list_arrow");
      var panel = document.querySelectorAll(".list_panel");

      for (var i = 0; i < arrow.length; i++) {

        arrow[i].addEventListener('click', function showDiv(event) {
          var ulelm = this.parentNode.querySelector("ul");

          if (ulelm.style.display == 'none') { 
            ulelm.style.display = 'block';
          } else {
            ulelm.style.display = 'none';
          }
        });

      }

    });
```

working example is [here](http://codepen.io/nseepana/pen/xOrYpv).